# How do I test the Asp.Net Core controller which has Db Context and Logger?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I have a controller with two parameters and need to test them via unit tests. Want to test 4 parameters, ViewBug, etc. But how I can make fake DB context and logger? I'm stuck at this moment:

```
        [Fact]
    public void IndexReturnsAViewResultWithAListOfUsers()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<AircraftsController>();
        var controller = new AircraftsController(/*params*/);

        // Act

        // Assert
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
 public class AircraftsController : Controller
{
    #region DbContext, Logger
    public AppDbContext Context { get; }
    private readonly ILogger<AircraftsController> _logger;

    public AircraftsController(AppDbContext context, ILogger<AircraftsController> logger)
    {
        Context = context;      
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogDebug(1, "NLog injected into Controller");
    }
    #endregion



    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Compare(int vehicle1, int vehicle2, int vehicle3, int vehicle4)
    {
        var planesFromDb = Context.Planes.OrderBy(x => x.BR).ToList();
        planesFromDb.Insert(0, new Plane { Image = "~/images/EmptyPlane.png", Nation = "EmptyFlag", Name = "Select aircraft", VehicleId=0 });
        var selectedPlanes = new List<Plane>();
        ViewBag.AllPlanesSelected = planesFromDb;

        selectedPlanes.Add(planesFromDb.FirstOrDefault(p => p.VehicleId == vehicle1));
        selectedPlanes.Add(planesFromDb.FirstOrDefault(p => p.VehicleId == vehicle2));
        selectedPlanes.Add(planesFromDb.FirstOrDefault(p => p.VehicleId == vehicle3));
        selectedPlanes.Add(planesFromDb.FirstOrDefault(p => p.VehicleId == vehicle4));

        _logger.LogInformation("Log Message");

        return View(selectedPlanes);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well i for one wrap `DBContext`'s in `Generic Repositories`.From there its really easy to mock it :  [`GenericRepository<T>`](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/generic-repository-pattern-csharp-mvc/)  and test that.

Comment: You can use NullLogger<T> instead in tests at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen has suggested the in-memory provider is a good option for mocking an EFCore db context. It works for most things.

I have a requirement to use Moq for 3rd party dependencies so I'd create mocks for both. For the db context I'd use [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) (disclaimer, I am the author):

```
var mockedDbContext = Create.MockedDbContextFor<AppDbContext>();
```

Then for the logger I'd create a mock using `Mock.Of`

```
var mockedLogger = Mock.Of<ILogger<AircraftsController>>();
```

Easy one liners that you can then use to create your controller in your unit test. Overall I am an advocate of using the EFCore in-memory provider if it suits the unit test. Using mocks does have other advantages such as allowing you to verify invocations.

Comment: trying to use your mocks but get:  
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: <param> => <param>.Helis
    Non-overridable members (here: AppDbContext.get_Helis) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Comment: Sounds like the Helis member on your AppDbContext is not marked virtual.

Comment: i dint understand, what method i must marked like a virtual https://github.com/booooooogdan/web-wtversus/blob/master/WTVersus/Models/AppDbContext.cs

Comment: Dbset properties must be marked virtual for a mock to work

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core, you can take advantage of in-memory databases for unit tests.  There are two options, EF In-Memory database, and SQLite In-Memory database.  I prefer SQLite In-Memory because it gives you all the advantages of handling relational data, unlike EF In-Memory.

[Testing with the EF In-Memory Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

[SQLite In-Memory Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/in-memory-databases)

Below is a simple implementation for unit tests using SQLite In-Memory database:

```
    public YourContext GetDbContext()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var option = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection,
            s => {
                s.UseNetTopologySuite();
                s.MigrationsHistoryTable("__MigrationHistory");
            }).Options;

        var dbContext = new YourContext(option);

        //Added to recreate database and run migration for each test.
        if (dbContext != null)   
        {
            dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        return dbContext;
    }
```

And then in unit test:

```
var context = GetDbContext();
```

Alternatively, you can place the GetDbContext method in a fixture, so that you are only re-creating the database one time per test class.  Have a dispose method in the fixture to run the dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted() to clean up the data between test classes.

[Shared context between Tests - Class Fixtures](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context.html)